# cursor variable not recognized

Tags: android, variables, android-sqlite

I've got an int data in sqlite I'm trying to access to show the status in the activity. The below is the activity page with the getCA() cursor in the database helper activity.

I'm having trouble trying to get the data, in particular the 'first' figure which is an int as a variable to be shared outside of the apple class within the same activity. As you can see below, I'm trying to 'cheat' by adding the int variable df (set to 0, so it has no effect on first) to int variable first so I can essentially get the first figure.

But this new dfe variable is not recognized inside or outside of apple class? I've tried making it 'public int' but it says public is not valid in this context.

```
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    myDb= new DbA(this);
    myDb.open();                
    setContentView(R.layout.mainpage);
            getdata();         
              }

    private void getdata() {
        Cursor cursor = myDb.getCA();
        apple(cursor);              
    }


    private void apple(Cursor cursor) {
        int df = 0;
        if (ur.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                int first = cursor.getInt(0);
                int coma = cursor.getInt(1);
                String desc = cursor.getString(2);

                // Append data to the message:
                int dfe = df + first;                      

            } while(cursor.moveToNext());

        }

        cursor.close();

        ///this last line below, eclipse cannot recognize 'dfe' as a variable?
        int cot = dfe;
        }
```

Please help. As you can probably tell, I'm very new to android.

I guess essentially the question is how to share the variables that is derived from the database inside the apple class, with other classes in the same activity page? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

int dfe is define in loop so the variable can only access in loop, change it to method variable

```
// Append data to the message:
   int dfe = df + first;
```

fixed: use this method

```
private void apple(Cursor cursor) {
        int df = 0;
        int dfe;
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                int first = cursor.getInt(0);
                int coma = cursor.getInt(1);
                String desc = cursor.getString(2);

                // Append data to the message:
                    dfe = df + first;                      

            } while(cursor.moveToNext());

        }

        cursor.close();

        int cot = dfe;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. it works, but still need to initiate dfe, so "int dfe = 0"; instead of "int dfe;"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are new to Java too. ;)

In your code, `apple` is not a class, it is a method.
You define classes with `class Name` and it should be in a file of its own (unless you want an inner class but I assume you don't).

The reason you are getting that error is because methods don't set visibility modifiers on their fields, they are private to the method (or within the `scope` that they are declared. If you want access to a variable both in and outside a method (or loop) you should declare it outside in the containing class or method.
The same is true for your `dfe` variable, it is declared inside your `do...while` loop and can't be seen outside it.

You should read up on `variable scope` to solve your issues.

---

I'm not sure if you mixed up your terminology calling `apple` a class or if you actually wanted it as a class. If you did want it as a class here is what you could do:

```
public Apple {
    // declare the fields you want to store for Apple
    private int dfe;
    private String description;

    public Apple(int first, int coma, String description)
        // use the arguments to set your variables
        this.dfe = //some calculation
        this.description = description;
    }

    // define methods for accessing the fields
    public int getDfe() {
        return this.dfe;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return this.description;
    }
}
```

And then in the method for reading the Cursor:
(I'm assuming it contains more than one result)

```
public List<Apple> getDemApples(Cursor cursor) {
    List<Apple> apples = new ArrayList<Apple>();
    if (cursor != null) {
        int tempFirst;
        int tempComa;
        String tempDescription;

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            tempFirst = cursor.getInt(0);
            tempComa = cursor.getInt(1);
            tempDescription = cursor.getString(2);
            apples.add(new Apple(tempFirst, tempComa, tempDescription));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    return apples;
}
```

Or something along those lines. Again, I may have misinterpreted what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your very detailed explanation. What you said makes sense. You answered questions I didn't even think to ask yet. You are right, its more than one data since I'm actually trying to access the preferences settings so as to show it back to the user.

Comment: I also tried to public void(cursor c), but the dfe variable is still not recognized tho outside the method. (thanks for explaining the difference between class and method, btw).